# Limit data in Chart.js with Flask/SQLAlchemy in python

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, chart.js, flask-sqlalchemy

**Hello everyone**

I want to use Chart.js graphs to show temperature and humidity data in a line graph. I have two tables in SQlite with sensors and temperature/humidity values. I succeeded to render a template and generate a graph per sensor. Now I need to pass the values into graphs per sensor, and for me that's the tricky part. It has to be the last 30 sensor-readings per graph and ordered by time.

**Background info**

In a zoo setting I want to monitor multiple exhibits and aquariums on temperature and humidity. For every sensor I want to display a graph on a page that displays the last 30 values of that particular sensor. The data is al stored in a database. I want to write the code that way so that if I add a sensor it automatically adds a graph for that particurly sensor on the page and displays the last 30 values of that sensor. To clarify it in another way: on one page i want for every sensor one graph with the last 30 values.

I can imagine i have to do something with querying like:

```
Sensorreading.query.filter_by(name=name).order_by(time.desc()).limit(30)
```

But the difficulty for me is to limit the data per sensor, so something like:

```
sensors = session.query(Sensor).all()
for sensor in sensors:
    reading = session.query(Sensor.readings).order_by(id.desc()).limit(30)
```

I already understood that it is better to filter in python/query than in the jinja code.

I know the graphs working per sensor with data and get nice graphs for every sensor. Now only the final step to limit the data per graph

[image]

**Models for SQlite3:**

```
class Sensor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    sensor_type = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    limit_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    readings = db.relationship('Sensorreading', backref='sensor')

class Sensorreading(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    temp_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    hum_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    aqua_temp_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    sensor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.id'))
```

**Render template code:**

```
@app.route('/sensorlog')
def sensorlog():
    results = Sensor.query.order_by(Sensor.id.asc()).all()
    if results > 0:
        return render_template('sensorlog.html', sensors=results)
    else:
        msg = 'No Sensors Found'
        return render_template('sensorlog.html', msg=msg)
```

**Jinja code generating graphs (sensorlog.html):**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h2><b>Sensor Log</b></h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        {% for sensor in sensors %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4><b>{{ sensor.name }}</b></h4>
                    <canvas id='sensor_chart_{{ sensor.id }}' width='800' height='300'></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block tail %}
    <script src="/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function buildChart(id, labels, humidity, temperature) {
            var ctx = $(id).get(0).getContext('2d');
            var dhtChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Temperature (Celsius)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)",
                            fillColor: "rgba(225, 225, 0, 1)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(225, 225, 0, 1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data: temperature
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Humidity (%)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 1)",
                            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            data: humidity
                        }
                    ]
                },
                Options: {

                }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            {% for sensor in sensors %}
                console.log('{{ sensor.name }}');
                buildChart('#sensor_chart_{{ sensor.id }}', 
                ["{{ sensor.readings|join('\",\"', attribute='time')|safe }}"], 
                [{{ sensor.readings|join(',', attribute='hum_value') }}], 
                [{{ sensor.readings|join(',', attribute='temp_value') }}]);
            {% endfor %}
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I can't find a solution to this problem, so hopefully someone can help me out. Any tips, tricks, code helps or links to usefull information is welcome. Any comments and suggestions about the current code is also appreciated, i'm just a beginner on his first project.

Thanks in advance for every help you give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion is close. You want to filter the reading query for the sensor you're on & order the query by time.

If you do something like this in your route:

```
@app.route('/sensorlog')
def sensorlog():
    sensors = Sensor.query.order_by(Sensor.id.asc()).all()
    if sensors > 0:
        readings = {}
        for sensor in sensors:
            readings[sensor.id] = session.query(
                Sensor.readings
            ).filter_by(
                id=sensor.id
            ).order_by(
                time.desc()
            ).limit(30)
        return render_template('sensorlog.html', sensors=sensors, readings=readings)
    else:
        msg = 'No Sensors Found'
        return render_template('sensorlog.html', msg=msg)
```

You should now be sending an object of the results for each sensor as well as the sensor information.

Then in your jinja template you should only have to change the javascript where you're calling `buildChart()` so that the `labels, humidity & temperature` arguments access the `readings[sensor.id]`.

Hope that makes sense, it was a bit hard to get through without having access to the data or app myself.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this out this evening. Yeah, i can imagine it is a bit of a pain to design code without the whole picture. I will let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: No worries. Accept my answer as the correct one if it helped :)